# Expression for people who always miss each other by a few minutes

Tags: phrase-requests

I would really like another way of saying/expression/quote for "people who always miss each other by a few minutes".

Comment: It would be helpful to see what sort of sentence you have in mind.  Just put some dashes ________ in the place where the desired word/expression would go.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might or might not be what you are looking for: "Passing ships"

Comment: Normally the full expression is 'ships passing in the night'

Comment: yes, it is. I was already half asleep when I was typing that answer :/

Comment: star crossed. or star uncrossed. {sigh}

Answer (score 0):

For the activity, Wikipedia says that such people are "playing phone tag".  I imagine that they could be called "phone-tag players".

Comment: I've never heard this one before. This is interesting